Error with fetching metrics / insights from media id using Instagram Insights and Mentioned Media API
i want to fetch the performance metrics of a post that mentioned me made by another public user but i kept getting an error that states that the object does not exist
i tried getting it from the mentioned media endpoiint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-graph-api/reference/ig-user/mentioned_media#sample-request) but the metrics available are limited so i can only retrieve the likes and comments count. i want to be able to access the views / impressions of each post too, and that metric is available on the /insights endpoint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-graph-api/reference/ig-media/insights)
but when i tried using /insights i get an error stating that the Object with ID <IG_MEDIA_ID> does not exist
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '12345' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33
  }
}

anyone faced a similar issue and was able to solve it ? would appreciate any help, thank you !
